# Connecting to Hive via Beeline using Kerberos keytab

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, keytab

Is it possible to connect to Hive via beeline using (kerberos) keytab file similar to the approach used for JDBC at

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingKerberoswithaPre-AuthenticatedSubject

PS : beeline does support connecting on a kerberos secured hive server with username and password. But I am looking for a way to connect it with a keytab file.
http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR40x/Configuring+Hive+on+a+Secure+Cluster#ConfiguringHiveonaSecureCluster-UsingBeelinewithKerberos

Comment: The second link, which you've pasted, shows how to do that. Path to keytab file should be passed in the hive-site.xml. Afterwards you connect by command: !connect jdbc:hive2://<hostname>:10000/default;principal=mapr/<FQDN@REALM>, where principal is a principalName present inside your keytab.

Answer (score 8):

I think you cannot connect with keytab file into beeline but you can get ticket with keytab using `kinit` and then pass the hive server principal with the jdbc connection string of beeline to connect.

```
kinit -k -t keytab principal
```

Connection string to connect with beeline

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM
```

Comment: Kumar and @greenmarker : Thanks for the reply. But even after attempting with the above connection string, it still asks for the _username_ and _password_. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Just press enter two times. No need to enter any username and password.

Comment: only need to change `hostname:port` _HOST@REALM -> this is not a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is **a bug**, but it is not **a critical one**.

Though you provided **kerberos details**, still it will ask you the username and password. You can just **enter -> enter**, it allows us to connect.

**Example:**

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM.COM

Connecting to jdbc:hive2://:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM.COM

Enter username for jdbc:hive2://:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM.COM: press enter

Enter password for jdbc:hive2://:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM.COM: press enter

Connected to: Apache Hive (version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.7-SNAPSHOT)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.7-SNAPSHOT)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
```